# How to Convert an NFA Diagram to a Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, nfa

I am reviewing regular expressions and have been stuck on the following question:

Provide a regular expression to describe the language of the following NFA:
[NFA Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6uDa.png)

I do not know how to answer the following question and I do not want someone to give me the answer to it. If possible, I'd greatly appreciate some guidance on how to either solve such questions or *how* to solve this particular problem. Thank you!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One approach: Step 1: Convert the NFA to a DFA. Step 2: [Convert the DFA to a RE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_algorithm).

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions might be useful too.

Comment: Uusally its easier and cleaner to convert an NFA directly to an RE without doing a conversion to DFA first -- the DFA may be much larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic conversion, you know that.

```
{q0, x, q0} becomes x*
{q0, x, q1} becomes x
{q0, x, q1}, {q0, y, q1} becomes x+y
```

Your diagram is DFA.
Your right-most state should not be `q1`. You have double `q1`. Name the most right state `q3` from now on.

I think the most difficult part is because there are outgoing transition from `q3` back to `q1` and `q2`.

We will start from the left part.

```
{q0, x, q0},{q0, y, q1} => x*y
```

`q0` is start state, `q1` is final state. Then `x*y` must always happen. The rest can happen or not, because there is transition back to `q1` from `q3`. So, we can write like this:

```
RE = x*y( ... )*
```

We are working inside the brackets now.

```
{q1, x, q2}, {q1, y, q2} => (x+y)
```

Because there is a transition back to `q2` from `q3`, we can write:

```
RE = x*y((x+y)( ... ))*
```

Because there is only one transition to reach final state i.e. `{q3, y, q1}`, then we put `y` at the last.

```
RE = x*y((x+y)( ... )y)*
```

The last part and the confusing part is `{q2, y, q2}, {q2, x, q3}, {q3, x, q2} => (y+xx)*x`

Explanation:

We are on `q2` and we have `y*` or `(xx)*` one or more time to get back to `q2`. We can write `(y*+(xx)*)*` or simply `(y+xx)*`. Remember that we have to be on `q3` to go to the final state by reading `y`, then from `q2` we need to read `x`, so that `(y+xx)*x`.

So the complete regular expression: `x*y((x+y)(y+xx)*xy)*`

Answer (score 0):

the answer by [ipramusinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10292170/ipramusinto)  is incorrect. `x*y((x+y)(y+xx)*xy)*` accepts the string yxxyxy which is not a solution.

check the related threads (the comments) on how to complete.

the regex is: `x*y((x|y)y*x(xy*x)*y)*`